# Calculate cubic surface

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

If {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{1,1,1},{18,20,1},{17,10,1}}  are 6 points in general position over the field of 23 elements and if
$E_{14,23,56}$ and $E_{14,26,35}$ are two Ecards points. Then how can find the equation of the cubic surface?

I have tried to compute the pencil of Cubic curve through the 6 points in general position. fo example the first pencil is as following:-
{x^2 y + x^2 z + x y2 + y^2 z + x z^2 + y z^2 + x y z}